# Coldfusion: passing a struct as String through url

Tags: serialization, struct, coldfusion

Is there a simple way to serialize a single-level structure as a string for use in a url?

for example:

```
?key1=val1&key2=val2
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
<cfscript>
// create simple struct
x = { a=1, b=2, c=3 };
WriteDump(x);

// serialize in JSON format and encode for URL transport
y = URLEncodedFormat( SerializeJSON(x));
WriteOutput( 'url: <a href="#SCRIPT_NAME#?z=#y#">#SCRIPT_NAME#?#y#</a>');

// now receive the URL variable and dump it
if ( StructKeyExists( url, 'z' )) {
    writeOutput( '<h3>URL Data:</h3>' );
    writeDump( DeserializeJSON( URLDecode( z)));
}
</cfscript>
```

Comment: I guess the only thing i can say about my solution is that it works with even more complex structs. Paul types faster than me! :D

Comment: I thought about this solution aswell.  It's more robust as you mentioned can handle complex structs but you always have to deserializeJSON the json on each receiving page I did something very similar in this example but via form:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392604/coldfusion-serializejson-example/10392839#10392839

Answer (score 13):

How does this look?

```
<cfset tmpStruct = {"firstItem" = "one", "secondItem" = "two"} />

<cfset myUrl = "http://domain.com/file.cfm?" />

<cfloop list="#structKeyList(tmpStruct)#" index="i" >
    <cfset myUrl = myUrl & i & "=" & tmpStruct[i] & "&" />
</cfloop>

<cfset myUrl = left(myUrl,len(myUrl)-1) />

<cfdump var="#myUrl#" />
```

Comment: Do not forget you can use also list functions ie `for (key in tmpStruct) {
     myUrl = listAppend(myURL, key &"="& URLEncodedFormat(tmpStruct[key]), "&");
 }` . Both work, though the json approach appeals to the lazy programmer in me ;)